# Scaling bar width on RangeBar chart using DataVisualization.Charting

Tags: .net, charts, data-visualization

I have a zoomable System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting RangeBar chart with a large number of bars.

The zoom function works fine, but as I zoom in, I'd like the bars to get wider, i.e. scale as the axis scales.  Is there a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found how to do it: just set the following on each series:

```
series.CustomProperties = "DrawSideBySide=False, IsXAxisQuantitative=True";
```